# how do I play sound in line with the iphone system's sound settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have mimicked the iphone keyboard tap sound. My problem now is that the 'Tock' sound is louder than the normal keyboard sound, and it still sounds even when keyboard clicks is disabled in the sounds setting on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any access to the preferences set in the iPhone settings.app